# How to Validate contents of Spark Dataframe

Tags: scala, validation, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have below Scala Spark code base, which works well, but should not.

The 2nd column has data of mixed types, whereas in Schema I have defined it of `IntegerType`. My actual program has over 100 columns, and keep deriving multiple child `DataFrames` after transformations.

How can I validate that contents of `RDD` or `DataFrame` fields have correct datatype values, and thus ignore invalid rows or change contents of column to some default value. Any more pointers for data quality checks with `DataFrame` or `RDD` are appreciated.

```
var theSeq = Seq(("X01", "41"),
    ("X01", 41),
    ("X01", 41),
    ("X02", "ab"),
    ("X02", "%%"))

val newRdd = sc.parallelize(theSeq)
val rowRdd = newRdd.map(r => Row(r._1, r._2))

val theSchema = StructType(Seq(StructField("ID", StringType, true),
    StructField("Age", IntegerType, true)))
val theNewDF = sqc.createDataFrame(rowRdd, theSchema)
theNewDF.show()
```

Answer (score 11):

First of all passing `schema` is simply a way to avoid type inference. It is not validated or enforced during DataFrame creation. On a side note I wouldn't describe `ClassCastException` as *working well*. For a moment I thought you actually found a bug.

I think the important question is how you get data like `theSeq` / `newRdd` in the first place. Is it something you parse by yourself, is it received from an external component? Simply looking at the type (`Seq[(String, Any)]` / `RDD[(String, Any)]` respectively) you already know it is not a valid input for a `DataFrame`. Probably the way to handle things at this level is to embrace static typing. Scala provides quite a few neat ways to handle unexpected conditions (`Try`, `Either`, `Option`) where the last one is the simplest one, and as a bonus works well with Spark SQL. Rather simplistic way to handle things could look like this

```
def validateInt(x: Any) = x match {
  case x: Int => Some(x)
  case _ => None
}

def validateString(x: Any) = x match { 
  case x: String => Some(x)
  case _ => None
}

val newRddOption: RDD[(Option[String], Option[Int])] = newRdd.map{
  case (id, age) => (validateString(id), validateInt(age))}
```

Since `Options` can be easily composed you can add additional checks like this:

```
def validateAge(age: Int) = {
  if(age >= 0 && age < 150) Some(age)
  else None
}

val newRddValidated: RDD[(Option[String], Option[Int])] = newRddOption.map{
  case (id, age) => (id, age.flatMap(validateAge))}
```

Next instead of `Row` which is a very crude container I would use cases classes:

```
case class Record(id: Option[String], age: Option[Int])

val records: RDD[Record] = newRddValidated.map{case (id, age) => Record(id, age)}
```

At this moment all you have to do is call `toDF`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame

val df: DataFrame = records.toDF
df.printSchema

// root
//  |-- id: string (nullable = true)
//  |-- age: integer (nullable = true)
```

This was the hard but arguably a more elegant way. A faster is to let SQL casting system to do a job for you. First lets convert everything to `Strings`:

```
val stringRdd: RDD[(String, String)] = sc.parallelize(theSeq).map(
  p => (p._1.toString, p._2.toString))
```

Next create a DataFrame:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col

val df: DataFrame = stringRdd.toDF("id", "age")

val expectedTypes = Seq(StringType, IntegerType)
val exprs: Seq[Column] = df.columns.zip(expectedTypes).map{
  case (c, t) => col(c).cast(t).alias(c)}

val dfProcessed: DataFrame = df.select(exprs: _*)
```

And the result:

```
dfProcessed.printSchema

// root
//  |-- id: string (nullable = true)
//  |-- age: integer (nullable = true)


dfProcessed.show

// +---+----+
// | id| age|
// +---+----+
// |X01|  41|
// |X01|  41|
// |X01|  41|
// |X02|null|
// |X02|null|
// +---+----+
```

Comment: The code I posted was only to prove issue I have....Thanks a lot for the reply....Although the 1st solution is elegant, but hardly works when its 125 columns in a file...and the file being dynamic in nature...even case class wouldnt work....thus Row being the only solution....  The casting solution is appropriate in my case.. Thank you very much. SS

Comment: Thats why have metaprogramming. Arguably there better languages where it comes more naturally than in Scala but it is perfectly possible.

Answer (score 0):

In version 1.4 or older

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.execution.debug._
theNewDF.typeCheck
```

It was removed via SPARK-9754 though.  I haven't checked but I think `typeCheck` becomes `sqlContext.debug` beforehand