# How to check that a value is the unix timestamp in Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

In the DataFrame `df` I have a column `datetime` that contains timestamp values. The problem is that in some rows these are unix timestamps, while in other rows these are `yyyyMMddHHmm` format.
How can I verify that each given value is unix timestamp and if it's not to convert it into timestamp?

```
df.withColumn("timestamp", unix_timestamp(col("datetime")))
```

I assume that `when...otherwise` should be used, but how to check that a value is the unix timestamp?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Validate contents of Spark Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33270907/how-to-validate-contents-of-spark-dataframe)

Comment: @user10465355: I haven't found anything related to the timestamp there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use when/otherwise along with the date parsing methods.  Here is some example code.  I differentiated using just the length of the string, but you could also check the result of parsing them.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

data = [
    ('201001021011',),
    ('201101021011',),
    ('1539721852',),
    ('1539721853',)
]

df = sc.parallelize(data).toDF(['date'])

df2 = df.withColumn('date',
    when(length('date') != 12, from_unixtime('date', 'yyyyMMddHHmm')) \
        .otherwise(col('date'))
)

df3 = df2.withColumn('date', to_timestamp('date', 'yyyyMMddHHmm'))
df3.show()
```

Outputs this:

```
+-------------------+
|               date|
+-------------------+
|2010-01-02 10:11:00|
|2011-01-02 10:11:00|
|2018-10-16 16:30:00|
|2018-10-16 16:30:00|
+-------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

If column `datetime` consists of only Unix-timestamp strings or "yyyyMMddHHmm"-formatted strings, you can differentiate the two string formats based on their length, since the former has 10 digits or less whereas the latter is a fixed 12:

```
val df = Seq(
  (1, "1538384400"),
  (2, "1538481600"),
  (3, "201809281800"),
  (4, "1538548200"),
  (5, "201809291530")
).toDF("id", "datetime")

df.withColumn("timestamp",
  when(length($"datetime") === 12, unix_timestamp($"datetime", "yyyyMMddHHmm")).
    otherwise($"datetime")
)
// +---+------------+----------+
// | id|    datetime| timestamp|
// +---+------------+----------+
// |  1|  1538384400|1538384400|
// |  2|  1538481600|1538481600|
// |  3|201809281800|1538182800|
// |  4|  1538548200|1538548200|
// |  5|201809291530|1538260200|
// +---+------------+----------+
```

In case there are other string formats in column `datetime`, you can narrow down the conditions for Unix timestamp to a range corresponding to the range of date-time in your dataset.  For example, Unix timestamp should be a 10-digit number post `2001-09-09` (and for the next 250+ years) and would start with `10` to `15` up till now:

```
df.withColumn("timestamp",
  when(length($"datetime") === 12, unix_timestamp($"datetime", "yyyyMMddHHmm")).
    otherwise(when(regexp_extract($"datetime", "^(1[0-5]\\d{8})$", 1) === $"datetime", $"datetime").
      otherwise(null)  // Or, additional conditions for other cases
))
```

Comment: Thanks for this idea. I would be happy to find a method that does not calculate the number of symbols. Is there any method that returns True/False about the correctness of a timestamp. Something like this: `df.withColumn("timestamp", when(!isUnixTimestamp($"datetime"), unix_timestamp($"datetime").    otherwise($"datetime")`

Comment: @ScalaBoy, I'm not aware of any method like `isUnixTimestamp`, and absence of such method isn't a surprise because Unix timestamp (which represents seconds elapsed since `1970-01-01 00:00:00`) is nothing but an integer incrementing from 0 to a 10-digit integer today.  Without a date-time range constraint, validating it is no difference from validating a generic non-negative `Long`.